# Inserting the previous date's info if the current is empty Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g

I have one table which hold following information

Table1 is a subquery, in order to simplify I will just use the resulted table:

```
| Account_No | Dept_ID | Currency| Amount | Date_2(dd/mm/yyyy)|
+------------+---------+---------+--------+-------------------+
| 1          | 1       | USD     | 50     | 03/01/2017        |
| 1          | 2       | EUR     | 25     | 01/01/2017        |
| 1          | 3       | USD     | 51     | 01/01/2017        |
| 1          | 1       | GBP     | 45     | 01/01/2017        |
| 1          | 2       | USD     | 65     | 02/01/2017        |
```

**Amount** is the amount of money at the end of the day of the account of specified currency of some department at that date. What is more that there can be variation of the same account by **Currency** and **Dept_ID**(Same Account_no but different currency and/or department ID) what I mean is that PK is combination of Account_no, Dept_ID and Currency.

I am trying to attach that table to the dates table which has everyday of some specified range:

Dates table:

```
|   Date_1   |
+------------+
| 01/01/2017 |
| 02/01/2017 |
| 03/01/2017 |
| 04/01/2017 |
| 05/01/2017 |
...
```

The expected result is:

```
|   Date_1   | Account_No | Dept_ID | Currency| Amount | Date_2(dd/mm/yyyy)|
+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+-------------------+
| 01/01/2017 | 1          | 1       | USD     | 0      |                   |
| 01/01/2017 | 1          | 2       | USD     | 0      |                   |
| 01/01/2017 | 1          | 2       | EUR     | 25     | 01/01/2017        |
| 01/01/2017 | 1          | 3       | USD     | 51     | 01/01/2017        |
| 01/01/2017 | 1          | 1       | GBP     | 45     | 01/01/2017        |
| 02/01/2017 | 1          | 2       | USD     | 65     | 02/01/2017        |
| 02/01/2017 | 1          | 2       | EUR     | 25     |                   |
| 02/01/2017 | 1          | 3       | USD     | 51     |                   |
| 02/01/2017 | 1          | 1       | GBP     | 45     |                   |
| 02/01/2017 | 1          | 1       | USD     | 0      |                   |
| 03/01/2017 | 1          | 1       | USD     | 50     | 03/01/2017        |
| 03/01/2017 | 1          | 1       | GBP     | 45     |                   |
| 03/01/2017 | 1          | 3       | USD     | 51     |                   |
| 03/01/2017 | 1          | 2       | EUR     | 25     |                   |
| 03/01/2017 | 1          | 2       | USD     | 65     |                   |
```

So that for every date in **Dates** table I would have information from **Table1**, if the information is missing then it should select previous days' info. I have done the query of left joining but have no idea on how to fill the prev day's data into missing fields

```
SELECT * FROM DATES A LEFT JOIN TABLE1 B ON A.DATE_1 = B.DATE_2;
```

I get

```
|   Date_1   | Account_No | Dept_ID | Currency| Amount | Date_2(dd/mm/yyyy)|
+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+-------------------+
| 01/01/2017 | 1          | 2       | EUR     | 25     | 01/01/2017        |
| 01/01/2017 | 1          | 3       | USD     | 51     | 01/01/2017        |
| 01/01/2017 | 1          | 1       | GBP     | 45     | 01/01/2017        |
| 02/01/2017 | 1          | 2       | USD     | 65     | 02/01/2017        |
| 03/01/2017 | 1          | 1       | USD     | 50     | 03/01/2017        |
| 04/01/2017 |            |         |         |        |                   |
...
```

Advice on how to proceed is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with a [partition outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) plus a case statement that decides whether to put the current amount or the previous available amount if there isn't a current amount, like so:

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT 1 account_no, 1 dept_id, 'USD' currency, 50 amount, to_date('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 1 account_no, 2 dept_id, 'EUR' currency, 25 amount, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 1 account_no, 3 dept_id, 'USD' currency, 51 amount, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 1 account_no, 1 dept_id, 'GBP' currency, 45 amount, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 1 account_no, 2 dept_id, 'USD' currency, 65 amount, to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2 FROM dual),
      dates AS (SELECT to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT to_date('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT to_date('04/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT to_date('05/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual)
SELECT d.date_1,
       t1.account_no,
       t1.dept_id,
       t1.currency,
       CASE WHEN t1.amount is NULL THEN
                 LAG(t1.amount, 1, 0) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY t1.account_no, t1.dept_id, t1.currency ORDER BY d.date_1)
            ELSE t1.amount
       END amount,
       t1.date_2
FROM   dates d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1 PARTITION BY (t1.account_no, t1.dept_id, t1.currency)
         ON d.date_1 = t1.date_2
ORDER BY d.date_1,
         t1.account_no,
         t1.dept_id,
         t1.currency;

DATE_1      ACCOUNT_NO    DEPT_ID CURRENCY     AMOUNT DATE_2
----------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- -----------
01/01/2017           1          1 GBP              45 01/01/2017
01/01/2017           1          1 USD               0 
01/01/2017           1          2 EUR              25 01/01/2017
01/01/2017           1          2 USD               0 
01/01/2017           1          3 USD              51 01/01/2017
02/01/2017           1          1 GBP              45 
02/01/2017           1          1 USD               0 
02/01/2017           1          2 EUR              25 
02/01/2017           1          2 USD              65 02/01/2017
02/01/2017           1          3 USD              51 
03/01/2017           1          1 GBP              45 
03/01/2017           1          1 USD              50 03/01/2017
03/01/2017           1          2 EUR              25 
03/01/2017           1          2 USD              65 
03/01/2017           1          3 USD              51 
04/01/2017           1          1 GBP              45 
04/01/2017           1          1 USD              50 
04/01/2017           1          2 EUR              25 
04/01/2017           1          2 USD              65 
04/01/2017           1          3 USD              51 
05/01/2017           1          1 GBP              45 
05/01/2017           1          1 USD              50 
05/01/2017           1          2 EUR              25 
05/01/2017           1          2 USD              65 
05/01/2017           1          3 USD              51
```

N.B. If you are on a version of Oracle before 11.2, lag won't know about ignore nulls. You can use the following instead to simulate the same effect:

```
nvl(last_value(t1.amount) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY t1.account_no, t1.dept_id, t1.currency ORDER BY d.date_1), 0)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for help, I think you misunderstood me a bit, the `nvl` from your code will return 0 if it is not in the **table1**, however what I am trying to do, is to return the previous day's information if the current is null, for example in 05/01/2017 it would return `amount = 50` for `account_no =1` and `dept_id = 1` because no operation was done it would be the same as in the last day when operation was done

Comment: Ok, in which case you'll need a lag or last_value instead of the nvl.

Comment: Yes I think so too, this is what I am currently researching, thanks to @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer that should work as you expect - apologies for missing your actual requirement!

Comment: Indeed, I have came to the same conclusion, That there is no `IGNORE NULLS` for lag in Oracle 10g, and unfortunately my db is 10.2.

Comment: although I have used `coalesce(t1.amount, last_value(t1.amount IGNORE NULLS) over (PARTITION BY t1.account_no, t1.dept_id, t1.currency ORDER BY d.date_1), 0) as amount`

Comment: Yeah, the ignore nulls functionality wasn't added until 11.2. Coalesce is a good alternative to NVL. *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `lag()` with the `ignore nulls` option.  I think this is what you want:

```
select d.date_1, a.account_no,
       coalesce(dept_id,
                lag(dept_id ignore nulls) over (partition by t1.account_no order by d.date_1)
               ) as dept_id,
       coalesce(currency,
                lag(currency ignore nulls) over (partition by t1.account_no order by d.date_1)
               ) as currency,
       coalesce(amount,
                lag(amount ignore nulls) over (partition by t1.account_no order by d.date_1)
               ) as amount
from dates d CROSS JOIN
     (select distinct account_no from table1) a left join
     table1 t1
     on d.DATE_1 = t1.DATE_2 and a.account_no = t1.account_no;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time, I am having trouble with `ignore nulls` it says `Found: "ignore" expecting: ) `  I tried to find the missing parenthesis but I didn't find it,  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Hatik . . . `IGNORE NULLS` is definitely supported by Oracle:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652.

Comment: yes, it is supported in 11, I didn't notice that it is not supported in 10.2, that is why use `last_value` instead, should have specified my version

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH table1 AS
    (
        SELECT 1 account_no,
            1 dept_id,
            'USD' currency,
            50 amount,
            to_date('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 account_no,
            2 dept_id,
            'EUR' currency,
            25 amount,
            to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 account_no,
            3 dept_id,
            'USD' currency,
            51 amount,
            to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 account_no,
            1 dept_id,
            'GBP' currency,
            45 amount,
            to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 account_no,
            2 dept_id,
            'USD' currency,
            65 amount,
            to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_2
        FROM dual
    )
    ,
    dates AS
    (
        SELECT to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT to_date('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT to_date('04/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT to_date('05/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_1 FROM dual
    )
SELECT d.date_1,
    t1.account_no,
    t1.dept_id,
    t1.currency,
    t1.amount,
    CASE (t1.date_2)
        WHEN d.date_1
        THEN t1.date_2
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM table1 t1,
    dates d
ORDER BY d.date_1,
    t1.account_no,
    t1.dept_id,
    t1.currency;
```